# Angular UI Router Set Scope/Variable

Tags: angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router

I have an Angular app using the Ui Router for routing purposes. Each time I change the router, I would like to change the header of the page, and it seems like the $stateProvider would be the easiest way to do that. I have something like this for the $stateProvider:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('index', {
        url: "/",
        views: {
            "rightContainer": { templateUrl: "viewA.html" },
        },
        controller: function ($scope) {
            $scope.data.header = "Header 1"
        }
    })
    .state('details', {
        url: "/details",
        views: {
            "rightContainer": { templateUrl: "ViewB.html" },
        },
        controller: function ($scope) {
            $scope.data.header = "Header 2"
        }
    });
```

I then want to have the header:

```
    <div data-ng-controller="mainCtrl">
                <div class='bg'>{{data.header}}</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: May be it's better using data https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#attach-custom-data-to-state-objects

Answer (score 1):

You can use data https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#attach-custom-data-to-state-objects
or just an other approach

```
.run(function ($state,$rootScope$filter,WindowUtils) {
        $rootScope.$state = $state;
        $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(event, toState) {
            var stateName = toState.name;
            //switch 
            WindowUtils.setTitle(stateName);
         });
    })
    .factory('WindowUtils', function($window) {
        return {
            setTitle:function(title){
                var sep = ' - ';
                var current = $window.document.title.split(sep)[0];
                $window.document.title = current + sep + title;
            }
        };
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

The `.state` object has a `data` property for exactly what your trying to achieve. Just add `data: {header: "Header 1"}` to .`state` like so:

```
$stateProvider
.state('index', {
    url: "/",
    views: {
        "rightContainer": { templateUrl: "viewA.html" },
    },
    data: {header: "Header 1"}
})
```

**Edit/Update**

To access that `data` for page titles etc, its best if you use one `controller` for the `index.html <head>`, and use `$scope.$on` to push changes to a `$scope.header` on route change events. I would recommend having a look at the https://github.com/ngbp/ngbp project boilerplate for a working example.

**HTML**

https://github.com/ngbp/ngbp/blob/v0.3.2-release/src/index.html

```
<html ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <head>
        <title ng-bind="header"></title>
        ...
    </head>
```

**app.js**

https://github.com/ngbp/ngbp/blob/v0.3.2-release/src/app/app.js

```
.controller( 'AppCtrl', function AppCtrl ( $scope, $location ) {
    $scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
    if ( angular.isDefined( toState.data.header ) ) {
        $scope.header = toState.data.header;
    }
});
```

Comment: This definitely seems to be the way to go, but how do I then access it. Doing it the way the docs suggest does not work.

.controller("mainCtrl", function ($scope, $state){
   var header = $state.current.data.header;
}

Comment: Look at the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26922451/angular-ui-router-variable-in-nested-view In other words you'd probably be able to get it by adding $state as paramterer to controller and then accessing it by $state.current.data.header