# Angular ui-router variable in nested view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, view, angular-ui-router

I'm currently working on an app where I have multiple nested views, they sort of look like this:

```
- ui-view 
  - ui-view="header"
  - ui-view="nav"
  - ui-view="body"
```

My states are defined as follows:

```
.state('index', {
   url: '', // default route
   templateUrl: 'welcome.html'
})
.state('app', {
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'app.template.html' // This template contains the 3 different ui-views
})

// I'm using a different state here so I can set the navigation and header by default
.state('in-app', { 
    parent: 'app',
    abstract: true,
    views: {
       'nav@app': { '...' },
       'header@app': { '...' }
    }
})

// In-app routes
.state('dashboard', {
     parent: 'in-app',
     url: '/app/dashboard'
     views: {
         'body@app': { '...' }
    }
})
.state('users', {
     parent: 'in-app',
     url: '/app/users'
     views: {
         'body@app': { '...' }
    }
})
.state('settings', {
     parent: 'in-app',
     url: '/app/settings'
     views: {
         'body@app': { '...' }
    }
})
```

At the moment this works great, but for the `in-app routes` I would like to define a title that is displayed in the `header@app` view.
What would be the best way to do this? At the moment I can only think of either setting a variable on the `$rootScope`, or sending out an event. But for both of those I would need a controller.

Is there a way I could do this directly from my routes config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sample applicaiton of the UI-Router, uses this code:

#### [ui-router / sample / app / app.js](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/blob/master/sample/app/app.js#L10)

```
.run(
[ '$rootScope', '$state', '$stateParams',
    function ($rootScope, $state, $stateParams) {
    // It's very handy to add references to $state and $stateParams to the $rootScope
    // so that you can access them from any scope within your applications.For example,
    // <li ng-class="{ active: $state.includes('contacts.list') }"> will set the <li>
    // to active whenever 'contacts.list' or one of its decendents is active.
    $rootScope.$state = $state;
    $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;
}])
```

And that means, that with `data : {}` feature:

#### [Attach Custom Data to State Objects](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#attach-custom-data-to-state-objects)

> You can attach custom data to the state object (we recommend using a data property to avoid conflicts).

```
// Example shows an object-based state and a string-based state
var contacts = { 
    name: 'contacts',
    templateUrl: 'contacts.html',
    data: {
        customData1: 5,
        customData2: "blue"
    }  
}
```

we can do this:

```
.state('in-app', { 
    parent: 'app',
    abstract: true,
    views: {
       'nav@app': { '...' },
       'header@app': { '...' }
    }
    data: { title : "my title" },
})
```

And use it in some template like:

```
<div>{{$state.current.data.title}}</div>
```

Some summary.

- We can place state and params into $rootScope, so we can access it without any controller anyhwere.
- We can declare some more custom stuff via `data` and use it as a *title* ... anyhwere

Comment: Thanks, seems I didn't properly read the docs about this, this was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Great to see that, sir! `UI-Router` is bloody fantastic tool ;)

Comment: Yes it is! I can't believe something essential as this isn't done by default in Angular. Once you go `ui-router`, you can't go back.

Comment: @RadimKöhler that's great! Any chance to pass it to a factory to make, for example, an http call search using this title variable?